# Stop broadcasting of SMS for specific number

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to stop the SMS for being showed in the notification bar of device for a specific number. I have implemented the code but its not working well. Kindly help

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    String str = "";

    if (bundle != null) {
        // Retrieve the SMS.

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            if (msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("5556")) {

                //Stop Broadcasting message
                this.abortBroadcast();
            }
        .............
```

Following is the manifest file

MANIFEST

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.smsmsg"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smsmsg.SendSMS"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: On Which version you are checking?

Comment: minimum 8 and target 19

Comment: Oops!! Whats your Emulator Android version?

Comment: Put some toasts / logs in your onrecieve method/ conditions and see if your code reaches there, if not then see you registered your class properly with permissions. iF all is OK post some more details.

Comment: i had used the logs but they were not working. In my MainActivity I created "sendBroadcastReceiver" and "deliveryBroadcastReceiver". Then registered the receivers and called the SendSMS function on button click

Comment: and in manifest i have permissions for Send & receive SMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this line would be wrong

```
 msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("5556")
```

before comparing check what was the number coming??

Try this

```
msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("15555215556")
```

**EDIT**

If you want to `abortBroadcast()` then your receivers should have **High Priority** so that your receiver will listen the callback first when and only the type is [Ordered Broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Imp Note**
This will not work from Kitkat because there is option to select the device which app should receive messages

[Sms Receiving in Kitkat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

Comment: Doesn't works. SMSReceiver is separate class and i have not used or called it anywhere else. Is it a problem?

Comment: Registering the receiver in the manifest is just enough to get the callback

Comment: Are you getting the sms in both your application and device?? or only into the device?

Comment: On device only. Application is not installed on the emulator on which i send sms

Comment: Is your Application in your receiver emulator receiving the message?

Comment: I commented out the code of SMSReceiver class and still its receiving messages :(

Comment: How do you know that the SMSReceiver is not calling??

Comment: I don't know. I only used "this.abortBroadcast();" in onReceive method, and its not working too

Comment: Please use Logs or Toast to verify that the SmsReceiver is calling when the Sms Receives

Comment: Used it. Not entering in the SMSReceiver's class onReceive method

Comment: according to Android developer docs, priority must be bigger than -1000 and less than 1000 (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)